# Is there a way to start a Microsoft Teams Channel meeting using C#?

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams

We are wanting to start a Teams Channel meeting using C#. The idea is that the channel meeting will be running, and who ever wants to join, can join. We need to automate this, thus doing it as a user each day is not an option.
Looking at the Graph API, I can't find an endpoint that can do this. Does anyone know how to do this in C#?

Comment: opening the web link for the Teams meeting is not enough?

Comment: The idea is to create a virtual Audio Visual Water Cooler. There should be a room (Teams Channel Meeting) running which users can join when they have some off time between meetings. Here they can then chat to who ever is in the meeting as well. Something like TeamSpeak where there is running rooms people can join. We would like to keep it to Microsoft Teams to reduce the platforms users use.

Comment: This sounds more like a discord feature than a teams feature. I understand that you want to minimize the number of apps, but in that case, why not have a permanent meeting running? I am not sure if there is a max time duration for a meeting. Otherwise, you would like then to just create a new calendar event on Teams every hour or so, and add a teams meeting to it(?)

Comment: @Jazz. Yeah, Discord is a good example. The problem with Teams is that you need a user to start the meeting. Then if the last user in the meeting leaves it, the meeting ends. Then the next person will have to start a meeting again and go on like this. I know it's dumb, but starting a meeting is a deterrent for users. Instead of initiating the meeting themselves, they rather do something else. This is why having a running room people can just click into is a better idea. Seems like Teams is not going to supply this for us so we will have to look at some other app. Thanks for the info though!

Comment: Another option would be to have an account that is always connected (?) that way the meeting would never end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using C#, Graph SDK and using [onlinemeetings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API call.
You can use it using delegated permissions and make sure you have OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite permission set.
Here's the code sample:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
{
    StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2021-01-12T21:30:34.2444915+00:00"),
    EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2021-01-02T22:00:34.2464912+00:00"),
    Subject = "Teams meeting"
};

await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(onlineMeeting);
    enter code here
```

Check the [SDK documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview) for details on how to [add the SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation) to your project and [create an authProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers) instance.